# How move to the next record in a database

Tags: c#

I am writing a project in ASP.net which I have six text boxes to display the information of the next record in my database. And I also have a search button base on some selected field which will search out my first record in my database. I inserted the code for my first record into the search button event handler. The code is written below:

```
Using System.Data;
Using System.Data.OleDb;
Using System.IO;

OleDbconnection mycon = new OleDbconnection("");

protected void search_btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int i = 0;
    DataTable dt;
    String searchme = "select * from student where myclass = '" + txtclass.Text + "' and mytype = '" + txtclasstype.Text + "'";
    OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand (searchme, mycon);
    mycon.Open();

    OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);
    dt = new DataTable();
    da.Fill(dt);

    if(dt.Rows.Count > 0)
    {
        i = 0;
        txtsearbox.Text = dt.Rows[i]["Admin_no"].ToString();
        txtsurname.Text = dt.Rows[i]["surname"].ToString();
        txtfirstname.Text = dt.Rows[i]["firstname"].ToString();
        txtothername.Text = dt.Rows[i]["othername"].ToString();
        txtsex.Text = dt.Rows[i]["sex"].ToString();
        Photo.ImageUrl = dt.Rows[i]["photo"].ToString();

        // then I created a session to hold my dt.
        Session["dt"] = dt;
    }
    mycon.Close();
}
```

The above code is working fine for my first record but where I am having problem is from my next button which is written as shown below:

```
protected void next_btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int rowIndex = 0;
    rowIndex ++;
    if(rowIndex <= dt.Rows.Count)
    {
        txtsearbox.Text = dt.Rows[rowIndex]["Admin_no"].ToString();
        txtsurname.Text = dt.Rows[rowIndex]["surname"].ToString();
        txtfirstname.Text = dt.Rows[rowIndex]["firstname"].ToString();
        txtothername.Text = dt.Rows[rowIndex]["othername"].ToString();
        txtsex.Text = dt.Rows[rowIndex]["sex"].ToString();
        Photo.ImageUrl = dt.Rows[rowIndex]["photo"].ToString();
    }
    mycon.Close();
}
```

The error it shows is: `There is no row at position 1.`

Comment: Sounds like the where clause didn't match anything. Check the SQL to make sure it is correct.

Comment: If a only single record was found - dt.Rows.Count would equal 1, but only array offset 0 would be filled - your if statement should be _"if(rowIndex < dt.Rows.Count)"_. Also shouldn't rowIndex be initialised outside of _"next_btn_Click"_ as it stands you will only ever access the second element in the Rows array (if it exists).

Comment: `rowIndex < dt.Rows.Count` would be appropriate if you are getting rows by index, since arrays are 0-based in C# (meaning a rowIndex of 1 is the _second_ row).

Comment: Thanks so much I will try removing the equal sign

Comment: [SQL Injection alert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) - you should **not** concatenate together your SQL statements - use **parametrized queries** instead to avoid SQL injection - check out [Little Bobby Tables](https://xkcd.com/327/)

Comment: Thanks marc_s I will take note of that.